# TableClientConfiguration not found in .net6 as i updated core from 3.1 to 6

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb, .net-6.0, azure-table-storage

I have to update a project in which i have to update project from netcore 3.1 to net6
it was using

```
Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table
```

i have updated it to

```
Azure.Data.Tables
```

as per Microsoft suggestion

i have updated all other reference but now i am facing issue that

```
TableClientConfiguration
```

don't exist it .net 6

my project file is

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Azure.Data.Tables" Version="12.6.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Queues" Version="12.12.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Core" Version="3.0.33" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions" Version="4.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="5.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="6.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Moq" Version="4.18.2" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

even this microsoft for this class dont have help of this

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.table.tableclientconfiguration?view=azure-dotnet

any idea with what i need to update it
or do i need to change the implementation ?

Comment: Please share your `.csproj` reference package file.

Comment: The client configuration seems no longer needed according to the samples. What are you currently configuring on the instance?

Comment: @AlexAIT which sample?

Answer (score 1):

The [migration guide](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/tables/Azure.Data.Tables/MigrationGuide.md) shows a sample where it is simply removed.

The main settings there were related to how the connection to CosmosDB was done (Preferred region, Consistency Level, ...).

```
_tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient(
  new TableClientConfiguration { 
     CosmosExecutorConfiguration = new CosmosExecutorConfiguration { 
         CurrentRegion = config.ApplicationRegion } });
```

This is not available in the new SDK (yet):

- https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/28986
- https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/30943

Comment: These options were removed because the current Cosmos Table API does not expose this. The previous SDK utilized Cosmos' "direct mode" to interact with these advanced features.